# How can I match the android.util.Log with crashlytics?

Tags: android, android-logcat, crashlytics

I want to create a new class in my android app to use crashlytics logging. That I want to do is create some methods that match the android.util.Log and I want to call the crashlytics method within ( Crashlytics.getInstance().core.log). But I don't have clear how can I do it... Someone can help me?

For example, I can do something like this?

Copy all Log.class in a new class and do

```
private Log() {
    Crashlytics.getInstance().core.log
}

public static int v(String tag, String msg) {
    return println_native(LOG_ID_MAIN, VERBOSE, tag, msg);
}
```

.
.
.

And in another class.

```
Log.v(tag, message);
```

This could work?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far?

Comment: The code that I have so far is nothing, because I don't have clear how to do it.

Comment: Well. You might want to try to write some code. Even if that's just pseudocode, it might help others understand what you are trying to do, and point you to a similiar question or some relevant documentation.

Comment: I just add some pseudocode in the question

Comment: I don't know Crashlytics so I can't help you with an answer, but I can give you an upvote, which will help make the question more visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
private CrashlyticsCore getCrashlytics() {
    return Crashlytics.getInstance().core;
}

public void logDebug(String tag, String message) {
    getCrashlytics().log(Log.DEBUG, tag, message);
}
```

Then in another part of the app just call

```
logDebug(TAG, "This is a log message");
```